# how to prevent an Gated Check-In to put the Keyword ***NO_CI*** in the Comment

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration, tfsbuild

This Question is related to my Question
[Combining “Gated Checkin” and “Continuous Integration” Builds in Team Foundation Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10101144/combining-gated-checkin-and-continuious-integration-builds-in-team-foundatio) I Posted this Morning

Thanks to @pantelif I know that after a `Gated Checkin Build` build Continuous Integration Builds are prevented to be triggered as an (in mostly cases) expected behavior.
The Team Foundation Server adds to the Check-In Comment the Keyword `***NO_CI***` to do that.

In the Question you find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8044776/why-is-no-ci-still-causing-a-continuous-intregration-build) there is described that someone accidentally turned off adding this Magic Phase.

What I want is triggering Continuous Integration Builds as an expected behavior. So I want to avoid that the Keyword to be put into my Comment.

What I do not know, is how to do it. I searched the Web for a while after my initial Question mentioned above was answered but found no real clue.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can disable `***NO_CI***` comment by setting the [NoCIOption](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.build.workflow.activities.syncworkspace.nocioption.aspx) property of the SyncWorkspace workflow activity to false. A similar question and answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3810427/tfs-2010-build-continuous-integration-and-gated-check-in-together).

You can either follow this blog [post](http://donovanbrown.com/post/How-to-have-CI-builds-run-after-a-Gated-Build) to implement a parameter for your build definition, or you can directly set this property to 'false' in your Gated CheckIn build template.

Comment: yes...exactely that was the Solution :-) - Great help, thanks

Comment: Note, this doesn't work in TFS 2013 RTM or update 1, but works again in update 2. See http://david.gardiner.net.au/2014/07/disabling-noci-using-2013-build-process.html

Answer (score 1):

### vNext Builds - preventing the ***NO_CI***

For vNext builds, check the "Run continuous integration triggers for committed changes" option on the Triggers tab for a build.

---

[image: Configuring running CI for committed changes]

---

*See the section "Option to run CI builds" in this reference:*: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/build/triggers#gated